# frequency distrbution based on 24 hours

Tags: excel, time, distribution, frequency, hour

I have a power pivot table with a date time entry (which can be changed to any-type of output with a case statement) Format (2012-01-01 00:00:30.000) Which I need to figure out how many of these entry's for any day arrived from 1:00 Am to 1:59 A, and 2:00 am to 2:59 am etc?

How do I format the Bin frequency in excel so I build the hour buckets?

I do want to graph more than one day but that could be done on the SQL side.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make a new table to chart the frequency distributions. Here's an example.
[image: Excel example of "countifs"]

The formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$17,"<"&F6,A2:A17,">="&E6)
```

will provide what you want. You can adjust the limits for min/max with the chart shown. Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to easily share the excel file.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to the other answer which is valid, you can create a pivot table based off of your data and then group it by right-clicking anywhere in the pivot table, selecting "Group..." and telling it how you want to group the data. You can group by Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, etc...

Comment: Good point. I know nothing about pivot tables. Personally, I've always made a new dataset in Excel for each new chart I want to present. Perhaps I need to read up on pivot tables now!

Comment: Pivot Tables, in my experience, make working with data exponentially easier since it does all of the work for you. It just takes a little practice to know how to do what you want to do. I would highly recommend learning about them if you use Excel on any sort of regular basis. ;)